# Encrypt and decrypt string with c++, Openssl and aes

Tags: c++, encryption, dll, openssl, aes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a string with c++ openssl and aes cbc.

The weird thing about this is, on one pc it works, and on the other pc it doesn't. There i have only 3/4 of the original string, so the ending is wrong.

The other weird thing is, when i add a dll called "libeay32.dll" to the directory of the exe file on the second pc, it works, but not on the first pc.

In summary, first pc only works without dll, second pc works only with dll.

My question is, can this code be improved, and why this dll is needed on one computer but not on the other.

Here's what i've already written:

KEY and Iv are defines:

```
#define KEY "abc"
#define Iv  "abc"
```

Encryption function:

```
string aes_encrypt(string _InStr)
{
    string  EncKey,
            EncIV;

    AES_KEY enc_key;

    unsigned char * aes_key   = (unsigned char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char) * (32)),
                  * iv_enc    = (unsigned char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE),
                  * aes_input = (unsigned char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char) * _InStr.size ()),
                  * enc_out   = (unsigned char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char) * ((_InStr.size () + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE);



    memcpy ((char *) aes_input, _InStr.c_str (), _InStr.size ());

    memset (aes_key, 0, 32);

    EncKey = KEY;
    EncIV  = Iv;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        EncKey = md5 (EncKey.c_str ());


    for (int i = 0; i < 305; i++)
        EncIV = md5 (EncIV.c_str ());

    EncIV.erase (16);

    memcpy (aes_key, EncKey.c_str (), 32);
    memcpy (iv_enc,  EncIV.c_str  (), 16);


    AES_set_encrypt_key (aes_key, 128, &enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt     (aes_input, enc_out, _InStr.size (), &enc_key, iv_enc, AES_ENCRYPT);


    free (aes_key);
    free (aes_input);
    free (iv_enc); 

    aes_key     = NULL;
    aes_input   = NULL;
    iv_enc      = NULL;

    return string ((char *) enc_out);

}
```

Decryption function:

```
string aes_decrypt (string _InStr)
{
    string  EncKey,
            EncIV;

    AES_KEY dec_key;

    unsigned char * aes_key   = (unsigned char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char) * (32)),
                  * iv_dec    = (unsigned char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE),
                  * enc_out   = (unsigned char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char) * _InStr.size ()),
                  * dec_out   = (unsigned char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char) * _InStr.size ());


    memcpy (enc_out, _InStr.c_str (), _InStr.size ());

    memset (aes_key, 0, 32);

    EncKey = KEY;
    EncIV  = Iv;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        EncKey = md5 (EncKey.c_str ());

    for (int i = 0; i < 305; i++)
        EncIV = md5 (EncIV.c_str ());

    EncIV.erase (16);

    memcpy (aes_key, EncKey.c_str (), 32);
    memcpy (iv_dec,  EncIV.c_str  (), 16);

    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key, 128, &dec_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_out, dec_out, _InStr.size (), &dec_key, iv_dec, AES_DECRYPT);

    free (aes_key);
    free (iv_dec); 
    free (enc_out);  

    aes_key     = NULL;
    iv_dec      = NULL;
    enc_out     = NULL;

    return string ((char *) dec_out);

}
```

Output of first pc:

Input:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Encrypted:

> S^Wo◄┘"â▼~¼\é╣$╨L╡`aC♠·ñZ½h╠∟≥ä°╪╥=αp╙IφoCYN°☺§)↨XwY+☼▀╤M▓÷√NÉk┼≡<ák◄Ä┬÷∙z
>   ¼üt@¥≈╟∙¶√Ñù°7å²²²²½½½½½½½½ε■ε■

Decrypted:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Output of second pc:

Input:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Encrypted:

> S^Wo?+"â?~¼\é¦$ðLÁ`aC?·ñZ½h¦?=ä°ÏÊ=ÓpËIÝoCYN°?§)?XwY+¤¯ÐM¦÷¹NÉk+­<ák?Ä-÷¨zð+BñFb
>   YÙ]?s

Decrypted:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?WÎ»H+²²²²¦¦¦¦¦¦w$ö?ó:

Comment: If an exe requires a dll, it'll first look in the current folder and if it doesn't find it then it'll look in various system folders until it finds it (or will bomb out if it doesn't). Could it be that the second pc has a copy of an old/buggy version of this dll somewhere in a system folder so it's picking up that one? Once you put the right one in your exe's folder, then it would work correctly. Anyway, just a guess, but it's worth looking for this dll on the entire C drive to make sure there's no older copy lurking somewhere.

Comment: Honestly, with the possible exception of the *initial input* to `aes_encrypt()`, and the *final output* of `aes_decrypt`, `std::string` shouldn't be *anywhere* in this. And if you find yourself c-ctyle-casting in C++, odds are you're doing something wrong. Both functions leak memory, btw.

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. The `EVP_*` functions use hardware, like AES-NI (if available). See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two are broken for sure....

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    EncKey = md5 (EncKey.c_str ());

for (int i = 0; i < 305; i++)
    EncIV = md5 (EncIV.c_str ());
```

You would need something like:

```
EncKey = string(md5 (EncKey.c_str ()), 16);
```

Otherwise, the string produced by MD5 is truncated at the first 0x00 the `string` constructor encounters.

---

These are trouble:

```
memcpy (aes_key, EncKey.c_str (), 32);
memcpy (iv_enc,  EncIV.c_str  (), 16);
```

At best, `MD5` produces a string of 16 bytes. You can't pull 32 bytes out of the 16 byte string in `EncKey`.

And you are in trouble if either `EncKey` or `EncIV` has an embedded null. If either has one, then that string is not even 16 bytes.

---

And as Jim pointed out in the comment below, this is also trouble:

```
return string ((char *) dec_out);
```

It needs to be similar to:

```
string aes_encrypt(string _InStr)
{
    ...
    return string ((char *) dec_out, <some size>);
}
```

---

And your use of `AES_cbc_encrypt` looks wrong. You should stick with the `EVP_*` interface. For an example, see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Better, use an authenticated encryption mode like GCM so you get authenticity/integrity assurances, too. For an example, see [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

---

Finally, use a larger hash like `SHA256` or `SHA512`. MD5 is no longer desired for anything other than backwards compatibility.

Comment: This is also trouble: return string ((char *) enc_out); -- enc_out is not null-terminated, and, may accidently be null-terminated by null bytes.